# How to get the Parent of own class?

Tags: c#, class, parent-child

I have a more or less easy class created that looks this way:

```
public class PreviewItem
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public Point PreviewStartingPoint { get; set; }
    public Point ReleaseStartingPoint { get; set; }
    public double PreviewWidth { get; set; }
    public double PreviewHeight { get; set; }
    public double ReleaseWidth { get; set; }
    public double ReleaseHeight { get; set; }
    public Border PreviewBorder { get; set; }
    public DispatcherTimer ShowTimer { get; set; }
    public int ShowIndex { get; set; }
    public List<MarketingItemNode> HandleList { get; set; }
}
```

Somewhere in between I call these lines:

```
previewItem.ShowTimer = new DispatcherTimer
{
    Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(previewItem.HandleList[0].Duration)
};

previewItem.ShowTimer.Tick += ShowNextItem;
previewItem.ShowTimer.Start();
```

Now I have given the Timer a normal Tick-Event. When the event fires, I want to find the "PreviewItem" by the sender. 
Something like this:

```
private void ShowNextItem(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    DispatcherTimer thisTimer = (DispatcherTimer) sender;
    PreviewItem thisItem = (PreviewItem) thisTimer.Parent;
    ...
}
```

But thisTimer has no Parent. How can I get the whole class inside the Tick-Event?

Comment: Maybe using `DispatcherTimer.Tag` property to store the parent?

Comment: All methods are working, but to use the tag ist the most simple method. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this perhaps?

```
previewItem.ShowTimer = new DispatcherTimer
            {
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(previewItem.HandleList[0].Duration),
                Tag = previewItem
            };
            previewItem.ShowTimer.Tick += ShowNextItem;
            previewItem.ShowTimer.Start();



private void ShowNextItem(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        DispatcherTimer thisTimer = (DispatcherTimer) sender;
        PreviewItem thisItem = (PreviewItem) thisTimer.Tag;
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Tag` property as suggested, or subclass `DispatcherTimer`:

```
public class MyDispatcherTimer : DispatcherTimer
{
    public MyDispatcherTimer(PreviewItem parent)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could inline the method:

```
previewItem.ShowTimer = new DispatcherTimer
{
    Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(previewItem.HandleList[0].Duration)
};

previewItem.ShowTimer.Tick += (s, ee) =>
{
    // create your logic for the tick event here:
    previewItem.DoSomething();
};

previewItem.ShowTimer.Start();
```

---

But, if you need to declare the timer within the class: `public DispatcherTimer ShowTimer { get; set; }` you'd better make the class take care of the timer itself.

You could create a constructor that creates the timer.

```
public class PreviewItem
{
   public string ItemName { get; set; }
   public Point PreviewStartingPoint { get; set; }
   public Point ReleaseStartingPoint { get; set; }
   public double PreviewWidth { get; set; }
   public double PreviewHeight { get; set; }
   public double ReleaseWidth { get; set; }
   public double ReleaseHeight { get; set; }
   public Border PreviewBorder { get; set; }
   public DispatcherTimer ShowTimer { get; private set; }   //  <-- private set
   public int ShowIndex { get; set; }
   public List<MarketingItemNode> HandleList { get; set; }

   public PreviewItem()
   {
       ShowTimer = new DispatcherTimer
       {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(previewItem.HandleList[0].Duration)
       };
       ShowTimer.Tick += ShowNextItem;
   }

   private void ShowNextItem(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
   {
        DispatcherTimer thisTimer = (DispatcherTimer) sender;
        PreviewItem thisItem = this;   // <-- for example, because you're in the object itself...
        ...
   }
}
```

use it like:

```
var myItem = new PreviewItem();
myItem.ShowTimer.Start();
```

But this means that every `PreviewItem` has it's own Timer  *(I think the `DispatcherTimer` shouldn't be in this class)*

I think a better approach is to create *one* Timer to take care of all instances. (iterating a list of `PreviewItem`s)

Comment: Was just about to write something similar. With an inline handler, you can capture whatever you want from the scope where the handler is set-up and pass that on to wherever you want it to go.

Comment: Thats a good approach, but no, you really need for every previewItem an own Timer, because they all change their content on different times with different contents. Its nearly impossible to use only one timer.